# Undefined control sequence with PStricks

Tags: xetex, pstricks

I am new to PStricks and Tex in general and no matter what I do, I get the same error message running a very simple code like the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{graphics}
% !TeX program = xelatex
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(2,2)(5,5)
        \psline(0,0)(1,1)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

These are the error messages I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 

l.12 ^^I^^I\psline(
            0,0)(1,1)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

And:

```
! Package inputenc Error: inputenc is not designed for xetex or luatex.
(inputenc)          only UTF-8 supported.
```

I don't understand what the error is since I run the document with XeTex and use TexStudio (if that is of any importance). 
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which engine do you use to compile?

Comment: I compile with XeLaTex.

Comment: Then you don't have to load `inputenc`. Is your document `utf8` encoded?

Comment: No, I don't think it is.

Comment: you say you get one error or the other, which do you get? You should get the `\c@lor@to@ps ` error if you use pdflatex instead of latex or xelatex, and you get the inputenc error if you use xelatex when using inputenc.  If you are using xelatex the file must be utf8 encoded

Comment: Well you should: `xelatex`and `lualatex` require it, and even for `(pdf)latex`, it is strongly recommended nowadays. It's the  only encoding with ascii working on all platforms, and most modern editors use it.

Comment: Delete the line with `inputenc` and it will work with `xelatex`

Comment: @David Carlisle: I actually get both errors when using `XeLaTex`, I should have used "and" instead of "or". Should I put `\usepackage[utf8]` instead?

Comment: With `xelatex`, you don't have to declare any encoding – but your code has to be in utf8.

Comment: no you need to delete the inputenc line (inputenc may not be used with xetex) and make sure your file is in utf-8 (all xetex files have to be in utf-8)